# Como faço para apagar automaticamente mensagem flash_data após ela ser exibida no codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
elseif($aulas_professor[0]['controle_aula'] == 0){
   $desativado = $this->session->set_flashdata('desativado', "O Professor selecionado N&atilde;o est&aacute; ativado ,ative-o e tente novamente!");
   return $this->calendario($desativado);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário. A [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#flashdata) informa que esse tipo de dados se autodestrói (A seguir, trecho extraído da documentação, em tradução livre):

> CoedIgniter suporta "flashdata", ou dados de sessão que só estão disponíveis para a próxima requisição e serão automaticamente apagados.

Se você está usando o método `set_flashdata()`da biblioteca de sessões para marcar, não precisa mais fazer nada para apagar esses dados.